# Strange NullPointerException in String Array Issue

Tags: java, string

Can anyone help me on this issue?

```
   'public class DataBase {
        static Article[] arts;
        public static int FileNumber;
        public static String[] FileList;
        static File root;

        public DataBase(String ID, String TA) 
        {
            File root=new File(pth);
            FileList=root.list().length;
            String[] FileList=new String[FileNumber];
            for(int i=0;i<FileNumber;i++)
            {
                 FileList[i]=new String(root.list()[i]);
            }
            arts=new Article[FileNumber];
        }

        public void phase_0()   //Initializare lista articole
        {
            for(int i=0;i<FileNumber;i++)
            {
                 System.out.println(FileList[i]); ******
            }
        }
    }'
```

I get runtime error at the line marked with ******. I don't have any idea about the issue. Can somebody help?

To be clarified, in static void main i first use constructor

```
DataBase db=new DataBase(...)
```

and then

```
db.phase_0();
```

and i get at the error on this last method at the specified line. Thanx in advance! The `PATH` is inserted when necessary, I assure that is NOT the problem

Comment: What have you tried when debugging? Is listaFisiere null when the exception is thrown? If so, where can it be set except in the constructor?

Comment: I don't really know the issue. I've verified and FileList (i've changed all names to english) seems to be null at that point.. But I don't understand why. I thought I've initialized the string correctly. I'm stuck on this idiotic issue for a couple of days

Comment: As per conventions, `public static int FileNumber;` should be `public static int FILE_NUMBER;`

Comment: @zengr That convention I believe only applies to constant values: [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: My bad, yes you are right, it should be `public static int fileNumber;`

Comment: How does this code even compile? `File root=new File(pth); FileList=root.list().length;` First of all, length() is a method, not a field, so you need parentheses. Second of all, the length() method returns a long and yet you are assigning the value to a String.

Comment: do your research better Code-Guru... it compiles

Answer (score 3):

You are shading your `public static String[] FileList` with this line:

```
String[] FileList=new String[FileNumber];
```

It should be:

```
FileList = new String[FileNumber];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your global `FileList` array gets overridden by the local array in your constructor. Remove the `String[]` from the local declaration to make it global.